# Excel 2007 - delete worksheet shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know the shortcut to add a new worksheet (SHIFT+F11).

But please tell me the shortcut to **delete** a worksheet.  I spend a huge amount of time on selecting worksheet through mouse and deleting them.

Please provide a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: **Right click the sheet name > Press 'D'.** In this way, you can keep your mouse cursor not moving if you wish to delete multiple consecutive sheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a macro in your Personals.xls file.
This is with warnings off so it won't bother you with verifying, but makes it more dangerous.

```
Sub Delete_Sheets_with_keys()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Tools >Macro >Macros and highlight the macro.

Click Options and assign a shortcut combination.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut from Excel 2003 is: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>. The newer versions  (at least 2007 & 2010) still honor this shortcut, however there is now another way to accomplish this: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat the action once you delete a sheet with the mouse.